# Parse Html Audio Tag Using HTML::TokeParser

Tags: perl, html-parsing

> I am trying to write a *spider* in perl which will parse all audio tags in a domain and attempt to download the respective `audio/mpeg` content from each audio tag found.

Below is a snippet from my code which uses the `HTML::TokeParser` to parse html in order to extract links from `a` tags:

```
my($response, $base, $stream, $pageURL, $tag, $url);

$response = 'http://example.com/page-with-some-audio-content';
$base = URI->new( $response->base )->canonical;

$stream = HTML::TokeParser->new( $response->content_ref );
$pageURL = URI->new( $response->request->uri );

while($tag = $stream->get_tag('a')) {
    next unless defined($url = $tag->[1]{'href'});
    print $url."\n";
}
```

> The above code snippet extracts all links from a given html page. This is used in a loop along with a hash of urls to crawl all pages in a given domain.

Below is another snippet almost entirely the same as the first except that I'm trying to extract **`audio` tags** *instead of* `a` tags:

```
my($response, $base, $stream, $pageURL, $tag, $url);

$response = 'http://example.com/page-with-some-audio-content';
$base = URI->new( $response->base )->canonical;

$stream = HTML::TokeParser->new( $response->content_ref );
$pageURL = URI->new( $response->request->uri );

while($tag = $stream->get_tag('audio')) {
    next unless defined($url = $tag->[1]{'onplaying'});
    print $url."\n";
}
```

For some reason, no `audio` tags are being detected. Is there something that I'm missing?

---

> Reading the [HTML::TokeParser](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.72/lib/HTML/TokeParser.pm) documentation I figure that I can not extract attributes of nested html elements.

Consider this markup below:

```
<audio onplaying="podPress_html5_count('http://www.example.com/mp3/Some Mp3 File.mp3', this.id)">
   <source src="http://www.example.com/mp3/Some%20Mp3%20File.mp3">
</audio>
```

I want to parse the entire html to extract only the `src` attributes of all `audio` tags found. Hence, if the html looked something like this:

```
  <body>

    <audio onplaying="podPress_html5_count('http://www.example.com/mp3/Some Mp3 File.mp3', this.id)">
      <source src="http://www.example.com/mp3/Some%20Mp3%20File.mp3">
    </audio>

    <audio onplaying="podPress_html5_count('http://www.example.com/mp3/Some Mp3 File 2.mp3', this.id)">
      <source src="http://www.example.com/mp3/Some%20Mp3%20File%202.mp3">
    </audio>

    <audio onplaying="podPress_html5_count('http://www.example.com/mp3/Some Mp3 File 3.mp3', this.id)">
      <source src="http://www.example.com/mp3/Some%20Mp3%20File%203.mp3">
    </audio>
    <audio onplaying="podPress_html5_count('http://www.example.com/mp3/Some Mp3 File 4.mp3', this.id)">
      <source src="http://www.example.com/mp3/Some%20Mp3%20File%204.mp3">
    </audio>

  </body>
```

The expected output should be like this:

`http://www.example.com/mp3/Some%20Mp3%20File.mp3`
`http://www.example.com/mp3/Some%20Mp3%20File%202.mp3`
`http://www.example.com/mp3/Some%20Mp3%20File%203.mp3`
`http://www.example.com/mp3/Some%20Mp3%20File%204.mp3`

> So I need to parse html files to extract only the `src` attributes of each `audio` tag present.

Comment: I fear the module doesn't support HTML5.

Comment: @choroba noooohh!!!!! What are options then?? X(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with HTML::Token but [Mojo::DOM](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/DOM) from [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/) can be used to easily find and extract the links with a familiar CSS syntax:

```
use Mojo::DOM;
my $html = '<body> ... ';
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($html);
my @src = map { $_->{src} }
    $dom->find('audio[onplaying] source[src]')->each;
```

And you can also combine this with [Mojo::UserAgent](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/UserAgent) if you need to grab the HTML files or the audio files from the network.

Comment: So the `@src` array is supposed to hold all the audio tags' `src` attribute?

Comment: @atefth: exactly. Works for me with your example.